# python compare "\n" escape chars with "\\n"

Tags: python, string, replace, escaping, backslash

Ok,

I have two strings, `"Hello\nWorld!"` and `Hello\\nWorld!`. I have to compare those that way that `\n` and `\\n` equals.

Thats not hard. I just `string1.replace("\n", "\\n")`.

But what if I have to do it right for all escape chars including unicode escapes, so manual replace is not an option.

**UPDATE**

Exaple case:

I read from file `Hello\nWorld!` (as seen when file is opened in editor). Python will see `Hello\\nWorld!`

I want to compare the last one with first one the way they are equals.

Comment: What is the bigger context here? Are you talking about the differences between printing a string and its [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)? Or differences between byte strings (`'foo'`) and unicode strings (`u'foo'`)? Or are these strings coming from an external source that already does some escaping?

Comment: `\x` is not a unicode escape, that's the way that unprintable *bytes* are displayed.  You'll need to show some example input.

Comment: X was an example char (any char). Edited, hope it's now more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using [`unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) encoding?

```
>>> 'hello\r\n'.encode('unicode_escape') == 'hello\\r\\n'
True
>>> 'hello\r\n' == 'hello\\r\\n'.decode('unicode_escape')
True
```

In Python 3.x, you need to encode/decode the string/bytes:

```
>>> 'hello\r\n'.encode('unicode_escape').decode() == 'hello\\r\\n'
True
>>> 'hello\r\n' == 'hello\\r\\n'.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
True
```